Ignore \0 entries in MySQL LOAD DATA statement
I regularly import CSV files into MySQL and sometimes the program that creates them has a random number of '\0' characters in the last line. I'd like to ignore this line when it occurs. Is there a way to deal with this when using the LOAD DATA statement?
I've reviewed the MySQL documentation for the LOAD DATA statement and I didn't see any obvious options that would help address my problem.

Use input preprocessing and remove those symbols.

Are they really literal \0, or are those null bytes?

There's nothing in LOAD DATA that will do this automatically. You need to fix the file before trying to load it.

They are null bytes.
